# Accessing kafka timestamps in pyflink

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink, flink-streaming, pyflink

I'm trying to write a Pyflink application for measuring latency and throughput. My data comes as json objects from a kafka topic and is loaded into a `DataStream` using the `SimpleStringSchema`-class for deserialization. Following the answer to this post ([How performance can be tested in Kafka and Flink environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59852001/how-performance-can-be-tested-in-kafka-and-flink-environment)) I have the Kafka-producer put timestamps in the events but struggle to understand how I can access those timestamps now. I am aware that the mentioned post offers a solution to this problem but I'm struggling to transfer this example to python as there is very little documentation/examples.

This other post ([Apache Flink: How to get timestamp of events in ingestion time mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49107932/apache-flink-how-to-get-timestamp-of-events-in-ingestion-time-mode)) suggests that I should define a `ProcessFunction` instead. However, here too I'm unsure about the syntax. I would probably have to do something like this (taken from: https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/master/flink-end-to-end-tests/flink-python-test/python/datastream/data_stream_job.py)

```
class MyProcessFunction():

    def process_element(self, value, ctx):
        result = value.get_time_stamp()
        yield result
```

What would be the correct way to do `value.get_time_stamp()` here? Or is there maybe an even simpler way of solving my problem that I'm not aware of?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

When you set up a table that is backed by a Kafka topic, you can declare a virtual column for the Kafka timestamp, like the `event_time` column in this example:

```sql
CREATE TABLE KafkaTable (
  `event_time` TIMESTAMP(3) METADATA FROM 'timestamp',
  `partition` BIGINT METADATA VIRTUAL,
  `offset` BIGINT METADATA VIRTUAL,
  `user_id` BIGINT,
  `item_id` BIGINT,
  `behavior` STRING
) WITH (
  'connector' = 'kafka',
  'topic' = 'user_behavior',
  'properties.bootstrap.servers' = 'localhost:9092',
  'properties.group.id' = 'testGroup',
  'scan.startup.mode' = 'earliest-offset',
  'format' = 'csv'
);
```

See the [documentation for Flink's Kafka Table connector](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/table/connectors/kafka.html#available-metadata) for more info about working with the metadata in the Kafka headers.

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering. Is there a way to do it with the DataStream-API?

Comment: I don't believe so, no.